# what does set() means in below pyspark rdd code

Tags: set

what does set([x[1]])) means in below code or in general what does set do ? Thanks

```
result_rdd = joined_df. \
map(lambda x : ((x[1], str(x[3])), (float(x[8]), int(x[0])))). \
combineByKey(
lambda x : (x[0], set([x[1]])),
lambda x, y : (x[0] + y[0], x[1] | set([y[1]])),
lambda x, y : (x[0] + y[0], x[1] | y[1])). \
map(lambda x :(x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1][0], len(x[1][1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

set is a data structure which holds non duplicate elements.

so,set([y[1]]) means y[1] data is put into list then it is converted into set,so that if elements in y are getting duplicated,it will not be inserted into set.